# Parse error: syntax error, unexpected ':', expecting ',' or ')'

Tags: php, syntax

В connect.php выдает вот такую ошибку: Parse error: syntax error, unexpected ':', expecting ',' or ')' in /home/f0431594/domains/svit-zadovolen.com/public_html/connect.php on line 2

Вот код:

P.S:заранее спасибо

```
<?php
$connection = mysqli_connect(  host: 'localhost', user: 'root', password: 'root' );
$select_db = mysqli_select_db( link: $connection, dbname: 'f0431594_practice' );
?>
```

Comment: https://www.w3schools.com/php/func_mysqli_connect.asp

Answer (score 0):

Вы нарушили синтаксис php. При передаче параметров в php не нужно указывать название аргумента

Например, есть функция sum, принимающая два параметра:

```
function sum($a, $b) {
  return $a + $b;
}
```

Вызвать ее можно так: `sum(1, 2)` (вернет `3`)

Обратитесь к [справочнику](https://www.php.net/manual/ru/functions.user-defined.php), чтобы изучить синтаксис подробнее